# How to do in Python a complex selection of rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, pandas-loc

I have a big `df` like below (just show the first lines, the real one has more than 60000k rows):

```
Id  Name    Age Friends
0   Will    33  385
1   Jean    26  2
2   Hugh    55  221
3   Deanna  40  465
4   Quark   68  21
5   Weyoun  59  318
6   Gowron  37  220
7   Will    54  307
8   Jadzia  38  380
9   Hugh    27  181
10  Odo     53  191
11  Ben     57  372
........
```

I would like to store in another dataframe that every 100 values insert 12.
I know that with `.loc` and `.iloc` you can store 1 value each `n` values (100 in the example below):

```
df1 = df.loc[::100]
```

I am trying not to iterate with a `for` within the dataframe since the `df` is so large, the process slows down a lot, is there any way with `.loc` to achieve this complex row selection?

Comment: So you want rows, 0-11, 100-111, 200-211, etc.?

Comment: as per @richardec,  please explain the question a bit better in order that others can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just trim off all the hundreds off the index values, so e.g. `200-300` becomes `0-100`, `123000-124000` becomes `0-100`, etc., and then filter for values less than 12:

```
filtered = df[df.index % 100 < 12]
```